# How do I add downloaded debian packages to Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: package-management, synaptic, debian, downloads

In Synaptic, when I click `File` **>** `Add downloaded packages` and navigate to the folder with the debian packages, the debian packages are greyed out, which means I cannot select them.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+question/18798) you are misusing this feature. Apparently, this feature in Synaptic is not for installing individual DEB package files.

To do this - without using the command line - navigate to the folder where the packages are and double-click one (or more?) of them. This will bring up the Package Installer and you should be good to go.

Comment: ok it's better than the dpkg -i ...

Comment: Will this work if I need to install a set of packages from files? (E.g., accountsservice and libaccountsservice0. As I needed in that case: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/952909/comments/9 )

Answer (score 0):

complementing @Mei answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/107521/46437

as an alternative to accomplish the final goal.

search for: Debian/Ubuntu: Making a Package Repository on Your LAN

(best shot, has the commands) [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository)

http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/debianubuntu_making_package_repository_your_lan/

https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-repository-ubuntu/

this way is easier when there is a lot of dependencies like trying to install yakuake on ubuntu 18.04 :)