# How can I update my custom repository?

Tags: package-management, localrepository

I created a local repository and I used it in my ubuntu clients.

This repository contains only some packages.
Now I would upgrade these packages.

How can I do it, as there are many packages and update them all manually is very difficult?

Have you got some suggestions to give me?

Comment: Do you mean updating the Ubuntu clients using your repository, or, updating the packages itself in the repository? If the latter is the case, then just re-create the repository as you have done in the first place, now using the updated packages. Also, please share how you created your local repository.

Comment: @gertvdijk--- Yeah he means to update the packages themselves.... anyway to know how to create your local repository please `http://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository` and rate