# Wine install cross dependencies

Tags: installation, wine, dpkg, dependencies

Help! When I try to install wine from .deb files from [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/wine) I can't because wine1.4-i386.deb and wine1.4-common.deb are cross dependent. One wont install without the other being configured. I have tried installing both at the same time and I get this messsage:

Errors were encountered while processing:

wine1,4-i386.deb

wine1.4-common.deb

Comment: why don't you install wine (1.5.13 is current version) from software center or synaptic?

Comment: i dont have internet on the pc with ubuntu.

Comment: sorry, did not think about it. you can try and get from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+packages and expandwine1.5 - 1.5.13-0ubuntu1 and then transfer all files to the other pc to install.

Comment: Are you sure these packages haven't have any dependency unsatisfied?

Comment: yes your solution did work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, 
First unpack both the packages and then try to configure them:

```
sudo dpkg --unpack wine1.4-i386.deb wine1.4-common.deb
```

Then use this command to configure

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Alternatively, you may simply try to setup a local repository with this two package and install them using it.

- [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)
- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing them both at once:

```
sudo dpkg -i package-a.deb package-b.deb
```

But why don't you just add the repository it is in? Then use your package manager to install it right out of the repositories resolving all dependencies for you.

Comment: already did, did not work.

Comment: @gabemai Please explain "did not work".

Comment: i get the error: errors were encountered while processing: wine1.4-i386.deb, wine1.4-common.deb.

Comment: @gabemai You should have more output. Please provide the other relevant lines.

Comment: wine1.4-common depends on wine1.4 however wine1.4 is not configured yet. wine1.4-i386.deb no such file or directory.

Comment: My suggestion whould be to try asking another more targeted question like "*How to install packages from the repositories on an offline machine?*" or use the Ubuntu forums.

Answer (score 0):

first ake a script file containing the following and place it in a usb drive.
(take the quotes out)

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -c http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine-gecko1.7/wine-gecko1.7_1.7-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1_i386.deb
wget -c http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine-mono0.0.4/wine-mono0.0.4_0.0.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1_all.deb
wget -c http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine1.5/wine1.5_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget -c http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine1.5/wine1.5-i386_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
wget -c http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/winetricks/winetricks_0.0+20120912~precise1~ppa1_i386.deb
wget -c http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-exe-thumbnailer/gnome-exe-thumbnailer_0.9-0ubuntu1_all.deb
wget -c http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine1.5/wine_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

then run the script from the usb of the pc with internet. it will fill it with the required packages.
then go the the pc without internet, and open synaptic and then File, Add downloaded packages and select the deb file from your USB.

if you don't have synaptic in the pc without internet, you can install it first

hope it helps, good luck.