# Storing deb packages on local media

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, tinyos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Is there a way to store deb packages (all or a specific version of package) on a local media (dvd, usb etc...) so later I would be able to install those packages on a PC which does not have Internet connection?

For example, these are the packages that I want to install on a PC which doesn't have Internet connection:

```
# TinyOS MSP430 GCC Compiler Repository
# Version 4.6.3
deb http://tinyprod.net/repos/debian squeeze main
deb http://tinyprod.net/repos/debian msp430-46 main

# TinyOS version 2.1.2
deb http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos/dists/ubuntu lucid main
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --download-only <packagename>`

Comment: you can browse those link find the package you need, here is the direct link to Tinyos version 2.1.2 http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos/dists/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tinyos-2.1.2/tinyos-2.1.2_2.1.2-20120813_all.deb

Comment: Want to only store packages which are downloaded? You can find them in `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder. If you also want to install them locally without using Internet on another pc, look at the above link

Comment: You want to download what you need or just backup your applications from your system?!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the deb only by the command

```
sudo apt-get --download-only <packagename>
```

Then you can burn the files to your DVD and make the DVD as a software source using synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center
Else you can make your own local repository. [read this to get it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)

Answer (score 3):

## Use [APT on CD](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptoncd/)

The gui interface for backing up deb files!

[image]

Comment: AptonCD backup installed packages but in his question he want to download and he didn't mention to backup installed packages

Comment: this is not the solution for the question

Answer (score 0):

you can download all needed softwares and updates through software center or Synaptic and then take a copy of you `/var/cache/apt/archives` and them on the offline machine do a `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`