# "Permission denied" error using dpkg-scanpackages and gzip

Tags: apt, bash, permissions, dpkg, repository

I'm quite new to Linux. I wanted to set up my own `local apt-repository` using instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository).
However, when i execute the script as:

`#! /bin/bash

 cd /var/www/debs/i386

 dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz`

This script when executed as :
`sudo update-mydebs` gives an error as:
`"Packages.gz: Permission Denied"`

Can anybody tell me, where the things are getting wrong !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm...try adding `sudo su` to the start of the script

Comment: @Ads20000: The script is being run as root, so that will have no effect.

Comment: @Ads20000 : actually the problem has dissapeared mischievously. Command now works, by directly changing to script directory and executing 'sudo ./my-script'. Anyways thanks for concern.

Comment: @VikasRaturi You should add your comment as answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: for sure @RaduRădeanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved itself by:
  - Changing to script directory
  - Exexuting using `sudo ./my-script`