# Where is the result of the "apt-get update" package list stored

Tags: apt, package-management

I have 20 to 3o computers on my network, and I have a copy of the Debian packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

But when I take this downloaded copy to any other machine, I need to run `apt-get update`.

How do I avoid this? Where is the list of packages, updated by that command, stored? I need to copy them as well, and use it on a computer which is completely offline.

Answer (score 4):

The packages lists are stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, copy all the files inside that directory (except `lock` and `partial`) to the other computer. You could also copy the `.bin` files in `/var/cache/apt/`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `apt-get update` command updates the `pkgcache.bin` and `srcpkgcache.bin` files in the `/var/cache/apt/` directory, so you have to copy those files too. Also please note that what you are trying to do it is not recommended!

Comment: well then is there any "recommended" solution to copy the package list ???

Comment: @meow I read about keeping a local copy of packages / sources somewhere, I think it was a debian/ubuntu package of some sort? Looks like there's several different ways: https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository