# Can Ubuntu run without internet?

Tags: administration

I have already installed Ubuntu on my laptop and I want to ask if Ubuntu can still run without internet.. Thanks!

Comment: Every OS _can_ run without Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need internet access to update software or you have to download the packages on a different machine and copy those via an external storage device. Also, you can't make much use of applications like the web browser, mail client etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a free open source OS which can run in all cases (with or without Internet). The only problem you can face when running offline is being outdate with the new patches and updates and sure you can't install new applications easily.

In order to make life easier for offline hosts the Ubuntu team had developed many methods to make offline repositories.

A repository is a container of binary(.deb) files which contain applications and software and other stuff to update or install new application.

[How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository). In this link you can learn how to make your offline repository in case you want to update your offline machine or you want to install a new application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run Ubuntu without an internet connection though you may find software installation easier with one.