# Do I need separate offline Ubuntu repository for desktop and server

Tags: repository, offline

I would like to update my Ubuntu servers and desktops offline without Internet connection. To update Ubuntu servers and desktop do I need separate mirror?

Comment: @souravc No, it isn't a duplicate as I am trying to decerne whether I need seperate repositorys for either the desktop and server. Or, if they'll require their own mirror. Either way, nice addition to the thread posting a link to that question.

Comment: If the system architectures are same and you are using same distribution of Ubuntu in both your desktop and server, same repo can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build offline local repository see [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)

The answer is NO. If the system architectures are same and you are using same distribution of Ubuntu in both your desktop and server, same repo can be used.

Further reference [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

Comment: Apart from clicking up and hitting the checkmark, is there a prefered alternative to doing so to accept?

Comment: @Miphix only hitting the checkmark is enough to accept the answer, up vote you may or may not.