# Ubuntu 15.04 server DNS server - private network (no internet access)

Tags: networking, server, 15.04, dns

Can anyone assist me in setting up a DNS server inside Ubuntu 15.04 server edition (inside VirtualBox)?  This is on a private network in an area with absolutely no internet access, so I need to download everything from home and deploy/configure it at the remote site.

Comment: I would suggest the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html) as a reference. It is all that I used. In your case you just wouldn't have any forwarders, as you are not on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc
to install locally you need to make a private repository

Read the following articles
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal 
and [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)
Follow the instructions and you should be good to go.

To learn more about BIND and how to configure you can refer to this link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto

Comment: Thanks!  Where should I download these packages from?

Comment: You can use sudo apt-get download bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc, this will be downloaded to the current directory, previously installed packages can be found in /var/cache/apt/archives. Please note you must read the articles and follow instructions there.