# How to get updates with no internet?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Does anyone know how I can install the Ubuntu updates (equivalent of `sudo apt-get update`and `sudo apt-get upgrade`) without an internet connection at that machine?  I've got internet at home, but not at the remote site.  I also would like to do `do-release-upgrade`.

This isn't a duplicate since I'm trying to *update* everything, similar to apt-get upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically while you could update individual packages, Ubuntu is quite dependent on a network to update... although it's might be possible to build a local repo when you have connectivity, and carry to the other machine (on CD?)... perhaps look at this answer:-

[How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)

You could upgrade from an installation CD, without an internet connection... one of the installation options is "Upgrade".

However you do it, this could be a tedious process!