# Full update package?

Tags: server, package-management, updates

So I have some servers that sit behind some firewalls and are not able to reach the internet.  Unfortunately, thats not about to change or else their sole purpose would be wasted.  This is ultimately good but poses a problem, I cant update them and they need to be brought up to speed as most will be fresh installs.

So I was wondering if there was a way to get a full system update in the form of a gzip, tar, tar.gz/.bz, what have you, and then be able to load it to a USB, mount and update.  At this point I've scoured everywhere I can think of but am not having any luck in the slightest.

Does anybody know if cannonical/ubuntu has something like this?  If not we will probably have to consider moving away from a ubuntu backend if we cant get updates any other way out to these boxes.  Either that or we will have to setup some kind of satellite server that's sole function is to pull updates but time is money.

Thanks in advance all,

Mikro

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my own local repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You can use apt-offline:

[Apt-offline](https://cartaslinux.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/apt-offline/)

You can download the update from other computer an apply it in your servers computer.