# Using an external HD w/ Ubuntu as a repository?

Tags: apt, package-management

One computer dies (Computer-A), so I order another (Computer-B) and decide to start Ubuntu anew. I have the HDD of the first computer in an external enclosure—and, for the next week, my internet sucks (and is restricted to about 1 Gb per day).

There's some software I'd like to install that's pretty heavy on the dependencies, all of which are installed via apt-get on Computer-A.

I'd like to be able to say something like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository Computer-A
sudo apt-get install [program]
```

I know that the `.deb` files are in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but I'd like to install them with the package manager, allowing for removal (and other things) as if I had downloaded and installed these packages from the Internet.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have not tested this, but take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository) question and in particular at the answer by BigSack. He/she talks about using `dpkg-dev` to create package lists for a bunch of `.deb`files.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/cache/apt/archives` is just a cache. You can safely copy all your old cache to the new one. While installing, if a package is there, it should be picked from there instead of downloading it.