# How to get name of local repository (for use with 'apt-get install -t')

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I've created a local repository as per BigSack's answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository) thread. I'm using the `/var/cache/apt/archives` of an old installation of Ubuntu on an external HDD (which I've renamed 'oldhd').

My entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this:

```
## This is a custom-repository for installing packages from my old HDD
## HP EliteBook 8460p Ubuntu installation. To install a package
## specifically from there, use: sudo apt install -t oldhd [package]
deb file:/media/me/9c4141dd-b628-439d-b464-0ff988fc849d/var/cache/apt/oldhd ./
```

Everything seems to work alright. I have the Packages.gz and Sources.gz files in the repository directory. `sudo apt update` completes without issue. The problem is when I try to install a package from this repository, I get an error:

```
me@Alcatraz: sudo apt install -t oldhd [package]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'oldhd' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a 
release is not available in the sources
```

This is the same error I get if I type in nonsense:

```
me@Alcatraz: sudo apt install -t kldjflakfsj [package]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'kldjflakfsj' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such 
a release is not available in the sources
```

This leads me to assume that apt just isn't seeing *oldhd* as a repository at all. I *think* my problem might be along the lines of my neglecting to perform some step to name the repository, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apt sees this as a repository just fine. I believe the problem lies in your repository not containing a `Release` file (an example: [the `Release` file for `trusty-security`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release)). Without it, you cannot target that repository using a release specification. You could pin your repository using `origin` information to give it higher priority (see [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84812/70524)).