# Ubuntu software for apt-get

Tags: apt

I created a software, and now I want to make software public.
If ysers will type on terminal command

```
apt-get install printx
```

then software will installed on their pc, and updated ~/.bashrc file.

How can I do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: I WILL NOT install any software that messes with my `~/.bashrc`. Also how will you "fix" the `~/.bashrc` of users who have encrypted `$HOME` directories and are not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You should **[create your own repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/184340/55365)**, put that online, and then add the repository to your repository list.