# How to download Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid)'s repository?

Tags: package-management, 10.04, rsync

Since Lucid's packages where moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` I'm a bit worried about availability of the repository and want to provide a full local mirror.

Are you aware of a way to download the whole Ubuntu package repository (lucid, lucid-backports, lucid-security and lucid-updates) other than `wget -r`? I cannot connect with rsync or ftp to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

*Edit*: This question is not a duplicate of [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository) since the question is about how to mirror from `old-releases.ubuntu.com` without knowing which packages to mirror (otherwise I could have simply used `apt-proxy`).

Comment: Are you trying to maintain very old equipment that can't upgrade to 12.04?

Comment: @tlhIngan I have to maintain an automatic provisioning of a virtual machine based on Ubuntu 10.04. I know that we have to update to a current version of Ubuntu but that's not the task I'm assigned to :(

Comment: You can try making a local mirror of the repos as described in any of the answers in this topic - http://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository

Comment: The Ubuntu archive stays "forever" . The `/etc/apt/sources.list` must be replaced with https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNalBaUFo0Q0VUY3c/view?usp=sharing → → Rename to `sources.list`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I know how to use `old-releaes.ubuntu.com` as package repository, but that doesn't solve the question of how to ensure it stays forever. There are many cloud services long gone which where promised to stay forever. And since `old-releases.ubuntu.com` is not mirrored like `archive.ubuntu.com` I'm worried even more.

Answer (score 4):

There are some mirroring tools available, debmirror is one of them (`apt-get install debmirror`).

The following script (basically one command) hopefully works. The full release is quite many gigabytes, so I didn't test this thoroughly.

```
#!/bin/sh
debmirror -v --timeout=300 \
 --cleanup --host=old-releases.ubuntu.com \
 --root=ubuntu --method=http --diff=none \
 --getcontents --no-check-gpg \
 --no-source \
 --di-dist=lucid --di-arch=i386,amd64 \
 --section=main,restricted,universe,multiverse,main/debian-installer \
 --dist=lucid,lucid-updates,lucid-security \
 --arch=i386,amd64 /mirror/lucid
```