# local deb file repository failes during apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, repository, docker

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004393/creating-a-local-ubuntu-repository-on-docker), I added some deb files and followed [the latest answer by @Wowfunhappy in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository) to create my own local repo. However during `apt-get update` I get the following errors:

```
Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_usr_local_mydebs_._Packages - open (13: Permission denied)
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Reading package lists... Done                      
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/usr/local/mydebs/./InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_usr_local_mydebs_._Packages  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_usr_local_mydebs_._Packages - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**EDIT:** 
I am using a docker container (Ubuntu 18.04).

**EDIT2**

I have found a [workaround from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004393/creating-a-local-ubuntu-repository-on-docker). However I still do get this message:

```
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/usr/local/mydebs/./InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Is this a harmless bug since I can proceed on installing packages? I am not familiar what "N" means.

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get update` - apt-get needs elevated rights (root / superuser).

Comment: Just edited the question. I am using a docker container, hence the `apt-get update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the line to apt-get update fixed it.

```
-o APT::Sandbox::User=root
```

complete `apt-get update` becomes:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::GzipIndexes=false -o APT::Sandbox::User=root update
```

Comment: It worked. I was installing few packages from Debian repository in Ubuntu 21.10.