# 16.04 - New version of package exists, but policy is not showing it as avaiable

Tags: 16.04, apt

I'm having this issue on a few servers.

A files got added to `/etc/apt/sources.lists.d/`, key got added okay and for some reason it's behind, won't upgrade, apt-cache policy is showing an older version.

Turns out on one of the servers, the content file was commented out. Once I undid that, it updated and the policy showed never versions.

But now on a similar server, same Ubuntu, same kernel version, same subnet, this is still not showing up.

File content isn't commented out. `sudo apt-get update` picks it up and everything. And yet policy remains on an older version.

`install=<newer_version>` says that version doesn't exist.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this? I have contacted the developer, who is trying to help, but nothing so far. So I thought I might ask here at the same time.

EDIT:

`grep -iR nameofsource *` Makes it show up only once, so that's fine too.

Comment: Have you fully checked the `/etc/apt/` folder with a `grep -iR nameofsource *` to make sure that it is not in another file possibly?  Have you seen your system actually pick up that source and not skip it and load it properly without any errors when you do the `sudo apt update`?  You have not mentioned what site it is that you are doing this from and trying to add it, so we can only guess what might be wrong.

Comment: Also, maybe look into setting up a local apt repository so that only one system needs to download from a site instead of many systems going out and doing it.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository

Comment: @Terrance yes, it is in the output of `sudo apt update`. And I manually checked the exact file, it's properly under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Nice idea with the local apt repo. Still stuck though.

Comment: @Terrance Tested, works, only 1 file, the expected one.