# Regarding installing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lts

I just wanted to know whether I should install Ubuntu 22.04 now right away or should I wait for the first maintenance release to be released. Because I installed it immediately when it was released initially. But at that time I faced some issues with the Zoom app and I was compelled to revert back to Ubuntu 20.04.
I would love to hear your suggestions regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Issues with the Zoom app*" seems suspiciously like bug reports that should be sent to Zoom (not to us).

Comment: You did not mention the nature of the issue, but using X.Org instead of Wayland might fix some screen sharing issues in Zoom. https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

Comment: It’s opinion based - but personally, I’d wait … if you need everything to work including 3rd party apps and you’ve got no other fallback computer, better to wait until the 3rd party apps have all been updated to work in 22.04. If on the other hand you can manage if those apps don’t work then go ahead with 22.04. But 20.04lts is a nice os in my view and for my use, I’ll wait a bit longer. You can of course check that you like the os in general with a live usb session, but if you’re going to try out 3rd party apps you might as well try a full installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it now if you want.

> or should I wait for the first maintenance release to be released

I doubt there will be an update to zoom. The snap version will already be updated in real time. The apt version likely will be kept as is except for security bugs.

Problems with zoom have nothing to do with Ubuntu. In the case of zoom it is probably best to either stick with one of 3 versions.

- Ubuntu: [snap](https://snapcraft.io/zoom-client) or `sudo snap install zoom-client`)
- The [latest](https://zoom.us/support/download) version from the zoom website.

Any will work where the `apt` version might be older than the snap or the website version. Meaning one of the 3 might have an issue the other 2 do not have ;) so try all 3 and pick the best one.

In case of issues with zoom it would be prudent to [report](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362003-Zoom-technical-support) that issue.

Comment: *"The apt version likely will be kept as is except for security bugs."* AFAIK zoom is not in the repositories. I didn't find a zoom PPA. The deb file in the zoom webpage gets updated from time to time.

Comment: @user68186 ]I have a zoom-client in 22.04 :) version 5.9/6 and it does not note if it is a snap so I assumed not-snap

Comment: There is a "hack" to get `apt` take care of zoom updates from the webpage, described in the [top rated answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271154/updating-zoom-in-the-terminal) here, but clearly it is not a PPA. My Zoom is Version: 5.11.1 (3595), but I am on Ubuntu 20.04.