# how to tell ubuntu to look in the original .iso for additional packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, system-installation

My new laptop's network card doesn't work and I need aircrack-ng for a dongle, which means I need dkms.  It's there in the package pool in the installation iso, but the installer tells me to reboot after install and then I can't figure out how to easily install anything from the pool, which seems like an obvious thing to want to do in this case.  I can dpkg --install the individual .deb files and take care of dependencies one at a time but bleeeech.

How do I arrange to look in the installation medium I just used for additional packages?

I don't mean to be mean but honestly as things are I'm not sure I'd have the installer even pretend to work if the network isn't there.  Everything seems to be set up assuming it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-create-a-local-apt-repository)

Comment: I see the installer/vm has your choice, so see answer 170348 (or the possible dups mentioned) to install packages from a local source.

Comment: These don't really answer my question, because it's crazy for it to be so hard.  It's the installation medium I *just used* to do the install.  How can the install be so unaware of it?  Also, when I click Other Software then Add... and type in an APT line, it silently does absolutely nothing.  Doubtless I'm getting the line wrong some how, but no error message?  Installer just seems like a joke really

Comment: "*I don't mean to be mean but honestly as things are I'm not sure I'd have the installer even pretend to work if the network isn't there. Everything seems to be set up assuming it.*" The developers are not here. They will not see your complaint. We are merely your fellow users offering to help. Please do not complain to us. It reduces our motivation to offer help to you.

Answer (score 0):

From the bottom of the launchpad, click on the dots, select Software & Updates, and at the bottom of the screen, there is a checkoff to select the DVD for searching for packages.

---

I see the active button on a full 22.04 install, and on a 23.10 ISO booted from disk. The full install has the commented line: # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS *Jammy Jellyfish* - Release amd64 (20220419)]/ jammy main restricted

I don't see an active button (like you see) on full 23.04 and 23.10 installs and a 23.10 vm.

---

The program apt-cdrom allows you to add sources for packages.  See the man page.  The list of such added sources is kept in file /var/lib/apt/cdroms.list.

```
cat cdroms.list
CD::a50676044fa2ce120515c2a6c57bb3c7-2 "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419)";
CD::a50676044fa2ce120515c2a6c57bb3c7-2::Label "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419)";
```

Comment: After launching Software & Updates I get a window with "Ununtu Software" tab selected, and at the bottom of that there's a "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD heading under which is what looks like a text field containing the grayed-out text "To install from a cd-ROM or DVD, insert the medium into the drive."   I tried popping the USB drive I used for install in and out but it didn't do anything.

Comment: If I decline the offer to reboot then there is indeed an entry in the Software & Updates dialog then lists the installation medium, and it's enabled by default, and apt-get install dkms (for example) works.  But it looks like it installs to the installation medium, rather than the just completed real install, because dkms isn't available after the reboot.

Comment: I've now also tried adding this line to /etc/apt/sources.list: deb [trusted=yes] "file:/media/bkerin/Ubunto 23.10.1 amd64/ubuntu/" mantic main restricted   , but this doesn't work either (apt-get update says Ign for everything).  I have no idea if it's becuase I added quotes to deal with the spaces in file name (unbelievable garbage btw) or not.