# How create image of ubuntu with software included ubuntu22.04

Tags: 22.04

I'm currently working on creating a custom Ubuntu ISO. I've been using the mkisofs.
but I not sure how to do it
I tried something , how can i make sure to choose the right path to copy
and what flags to use.
also how it working with the user?
it will copy also the user / admin user and it will be the same password?

Comment: Does this help: [Live CD customisation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)?

Comment: One of the easiest I have ever used was [Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator)](https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic)

Comment: thanks , download cubic... but there is no GUI for find and download apps. it make things more complicated. there is no software for gui , like create snaptshot for the current pc and make from this iso file? for example i tried download anydesk but there is error when tried with wget

Comment: Adding many application packages to your customized Live CD can make the size of your ISO image very large. You may also include the apps (along with all dependencies which is very important) in an ISO repository from which you can install the apps. If you are interested, please see my answer in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1501062/212123).